# SSH shows the wrong IP address when SSH with port forward

Tags: macos, ssh, portforwarding

My use case is I have to access AWS ec2 instances through a jumpbox.

Here is my SSH config.

```
Host awsjumpbox
  User sshuser
  HostName jumpboxhostname
  IdentityFile /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
  LocalForward 8022 10.0.168.43:22
```

It works when I do SCP command to copy files to the EC2 instance.

```
myusername % scp -r -i ~/aws/aws-keypair.pem -P 8022 * ec2-user@localhost:testdir
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:8022 ([::1]:8022)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:rrwr62yjP2cgUTT9SowdlrIwGi4jMMwt5x4Aj6E4Y3Y.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:8022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 19: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
README.md                                     100% 1064    24.3KB/s   00:00
```

However, when I executed SSH command. It returns a strange IP address.

```
myusername % ssh -i ~/aws/aws-keypair.pem -P 8022 ec2-user@localhost      
ssh: connect to host 0.0.31.86 port 22: No route to host
```

What is the cause of this issue? How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `LocalForward` and reverse the flow.

Use [ProxyCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyCommand) or [ProxyJump](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump). This will allow SSH to open a session to your bastion server transparently.

E.g. your configuration should be something in the line of

```
Host 10.0.168.43
  User root
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p sshuser@awsjumpbox
  ...
```

or

```
Host 10.0.168.43
  User root
  ProxyJump sshuser@awsjumpbox
  ...
```

Comment: If I add config like this, how do I execute SSH command?

Comment: Thanks Boky. It's really work. I'm using ProxyJump.